# During Select Statement refer to a fields declared name

Tags: mysql, alias

I'm currently building a report which at some point compares a few fields and works out the difference between the two.

It first checks which is larger field A or field B and whichever is biggest it then compares to C and tells me the difference. (Other calculations to follow but the answer to this will carry on through the scope of the project)

The problem I've got is A and B are calculated fields and I don't want to keep pasting this code in over and over again for each calculation.

Myself and others will probably refer back to this code regularly and it is already getting very clogged up.

The two existing lines are:

```
IF(MAX(LEAST(MANFU.height,width)) < 44,0.220,
         IF(MAX(LEAST(height,width)) < 68,0.340,
           IF(MAX(LEAST(height,width)) < 80,0.400,
             IF(MAX(LEAST(height,width)) < 90,0.450,
               IF(MAX(LEAST(height,width)) < 122,0.610,
                 IF(product_code LIKE '%_BB',2.508,'')))))) AS Volumetric_Weight',
```

and

```
SUM(boxweight)+SUM(Itemweight)+SUM(packagingweight) AS 'Expected_Weight',
```

I want to add a field that be able to carry out the following calculation:

```
IF(GREATEST(Volumetric_Weight,Expected_Weight) > Courier_Weight,'Overweight Item','Underweight Item')
```

Is there a way to refer to another fields alias?

Comment: Not clear what you want.

Comment: I want to achieve what the third snippet of code is doing.

Comment: @ChrisAardvark Wrap the existing 2 lines in subquery, then you do the calculation in outer query.

Comment: @Eric I'm not really sure what you mean. Are you able to post an answer?